# how to finish() when in two step processes?

Tags: java, android

(Activities A,B,C,D)

0: User starts Application

A: Go forward to B - backpress to  0

B: Go forward to C - backpress to  A

C: Go forward to D - backpress to  B

D: Go forward to A - backpress to  C

**A should never be able to backpress to D**

How can i pull this off?

bonus picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVFHL.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that A should never go back to D.

you want to end the wizard when A is finally reached, so you do this in activity D:

```
    //in Activity D

    Intent intent =new Intent(D.this, A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

CLEAR_TOP means to clear the back stack.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! Santa is going to be good to you this year ;P